# How to tell python to run a function over and over while we are typing?

Tags: python, nlp

I wanted to know if there is a way to tell python to run a function as long as we are typing new characters as a user input.

for example when I write hello, I want it to run a function simultaneously as I type each character! without me having to hit space and enter every time!

is there a method for that I can use ?

Comment: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`getch`](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) package provides this functionality. You can install it with:

```
pip install getch
```

And a basic usage example is like this:

```
from getch import getch

while True: 
    c = getch() 
    print("got", c)
```